# OData Feed / Power Query in Excel 2016 Not Retrieving All / Duplicating Some Records

Tags: excel, duplicates, odata, missing-data, powerquery

In Excel, I successfully connected to an OData feed from Data.Medicare.gov (the website is https://data.medicare.gov/Hospital-Compare/Healthcare-Associated-Infections-Hospital/77hc-ibv8/data and the endpoint is https://data.medicare.gov/api/odata/v4/77hc-ibv8).

However, now that I'm carefully reviewing and analyzing the data, I see that some of the data rows/records on the website (https://data.medicare.gov/Hospital-Compare/Patient-survey-HCAHPS-Hospital/dgck-syfz/data) are missing from my Excel data, while others are duplicated. After refreshing the data in Excel, some of the previously missing rows appear, while others disappear. The rows that appear, disappear, or duplicate with each refresh seem random.

For example, the record with Hospital Name = "Trinitas Regional Medical Center" and Measure ID = "HAI-1-SIR" is on the website but sometimes appears and then reappears from the Excel data table (__id = "row-6s6r~jx5f.wuje") with each refresh. However, the total number of rows does not change and is equal to the downloadable file.

Not sure if this is due to the large number of rows (>170k) in the data set. The only related discussion I have found is on https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2018/05/03/troubleshooting-data-refresh-performance-issues-with-odata-data-sources-in-power-bi-and-excel-using-fiddler/ but don't think this tackles my exact issue.

UPDATE 1:

Socrata, who provides the OData Feed service for this site, responded with the following:

> [We] have been able to reproduce this behavior in Excel, but I'm not sure what causes it. However, it does not appear to be an issue with the OData feed itself, as I can consistently access that row via my browser (e.g., https://data.medicare.gov/api/odata/v4/77hc-ibv8('row-6s6r~jx5f.wuje')), so it seems to be related to how Excel is handling the data. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find much online that explains why this is occurring, so it may be best to reach out to Microsoft Support to determine if they are able to assist with this further.

UPDATE 2:

After extensive troubleshooting and discussion with Microsoft's profession technical support, they (incorrectly) concluded the duplicate records were present in the OData feed. Reaching back out to Socrata support, they took into account my observation that this occurs with large data sets only and were able to suggest a resolution to the issue (see answer posted below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socrata Support found the issue and suggested appending a $top parameter to the OData feed URL, which resolved the issue for me:

> When you load an OData feed in Excel, Excel automatically paginates through the results in the background as it loads in large datasets, and this loading process is resulting in duplicate records. You can work around this by adding a $top parameter to the OData feed URL with a value that is greater than or equal to the total number of rows in the dataset, which will force Excel to load in all the data in a single request rather than paging through the results. For example, if you input https://data.medicare.gov/api/odata/v4/77hc-ibv8?$top=10000000 in as the URL, this will load in all of the records, and there will not be any duplicates.

Microsoft Office 365 Support confirmed "*that adding that $top command does indeed seem to stop the duplicates.*"

UPDATE:

Although the above $top parameter resolved the issue initially, I started  getting the following error message in Excel:

> Unable to connect
>
> We encountered an error while trying to connect.
>
> Details: "Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Resources.HttpResource: Request failed:
>   OData Version: 3 and 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. (An internal error occurred. Please contact Socrata support, referencing diagnostic code epsfgirt9lxlekyt89oq25x54)
>   OData Version: 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. (An internal error occurred. Please contact Socrata support, referencing diagnostic code 58cf025wln5br4qzw6lcrxh3a)

I therefore reached out to Socrata Support and they responded with the following:

> [We are] encountering the same error. I checked with our engineering team, and they said that they actually recently made some updates that likely caused this but also should have fixed the underlying issue. So if you remove "?$top=100000" from the OData URL in Excel and just use https://data.medicare.gov/api/odata/v4/yv7e-xc69, that should work and not return duplicate records like you had seen before. I have tested this on a couple of different assets today, and it does indeed seem to be fixed ... .

I used the regular OData endpoint (https://data.medicare.gov/api/odata/v4/yv7e-xc69) and it loaded without duplicates.